# Supplied resource is not a valid ldap result entry resource: ldap_get_attributes()

Tags: php, ldap, yii2, openldap, ldap-query

I've just started working on `LDAP` and trying make an connection between `PHP` & `LDAP`.

I've created small script to get all attributes information by referring [this](http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn33re632.html)
script.

```
$ldap_server = "My_Server_Name";
$ldap_user = "uid=platypus,ou=users,dc=crowd";
$ldap_pass = "My_Password";

$ad = ldap_connect($ldap_server);
ldap_set_option($ad, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
$bound = ldap_bind($ad, $ldap_user, $ldap_pass);

$result = ldap_read($ad, $ldap_user, "objectClass=*");
$attributes = ldap_get_attributes($ad, $result);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($attributes);
```

Connection is successfully made, its binding properly as well and `ldap_read` also giving me `#resourse id` but `ldap_get_attributes` giving me following error:

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>       ldap_get_attributes(): supplied resource is not a valid ldap result entry resource

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried specifying ```objectclass=*``` (note the lower-case 'c')?

Comment: Yes I tried that..but its not working

Comment: would you mind adding a call to ldap_error() behind the ldap_read()? Something IS going wrong and that way you might get an information what it is.

Answer (score 1):

ldap_get_attributes() expects the input parameter to be a reference to a single entry not to the complete resultset as stated on the [ldap_get_attributes-documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-attributes.php).

Have a look at ldap_get_first() or ldap_get_next() to get such a single entry reference.

Thanks to tejesh s for pointing in the right direction. I originally wanted to improve his answer but it was too much change :/

Answer (score 0):

ldap_get_attributes() expect input parameter to be an single entry not an array.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-attributes.php.

I hope this will help you.